# Show series $1 - 1/2^2 + 1/3 - 1/4^2 + 1/5 - 1/6^2$ ... does not converge

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof

I was wondering if my proof is correct, and if there are any better alternative proofs. Or maybe proof that use nice tricks i might need in the future.

$$1 - \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4^2} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6^2} \ldots = \sum_{n =1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2n + 1} - \frac{1}{(2n + 2)^2}\right) + 1 - \frac{1}{2^2}$$

Now we know that $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n + 1}$$ diverges and $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty -\frac{1}{(2n + 2)^2}$$ converges. Hence their sum diverges (I proved this fact). Hence, the series diverges. Any obvious mistake or better way of tackling it? Maybe using partial sums since i am clueless how to use them.

Comment: You are not allowed to split both summations. You need to look at the sum by itself.

Comment: You can't simply rearrange the terms like that (unless you already know the series converges absolutely, which this series does not).  But, since $\sum \frac 1{(2n)^2}$ converges, say to $L$, then we know the partial sums for your series are bounded below by the partial sums for $\sum \frac 1{2n+1}$ - $L$.  and that is enough.

Comment: I am not rearranging, and i am not splitting the sum. What is am saying that if i have a convergent and divergent series, then their sum is divergent. lulu can you elaborate on the partial sums? Thanks

Comment: Why do you have $1-1/2^2$ there at the end?

Comment: should be n=1 not zero. so these two dont fit in my sum

Comment: Why not leave it at $n=0$ and not include that stuff?

Comment: Because that how we defined it. $a_n$ where $n>0$. Weird but that how we use it. Does not really matter.

Comment: If $S_{k}$ is the partial sum for your series, then $S_{2k+1}≥\sum_{i=0}^k\frac 1{2i+1}-L$ and letting $k\to\infty$ shows divergence (I just wrote out the odd sums, but there is a similar expression for the even ones).

Comment: Why are you allowed to split the sum into two? I am pretty sure you can do that only if you know both series converge?

Comment: As to the rearranging:  you are grouping the terms in pairs.  If, say, $S=1-1+1-1+1-1+\cdots$ that technique would, on the one hand, yield $S=(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+\cdots = 0$ and on the other hand $S=1 + (-1+1)+(-1+1)+(-1+1)+\cdots =1 $.

Comment: If you insist on indexing starting from $n = 0$, then you can write $\frac{1}{2n - 1}$ and $- \frac{1}{(2n)^2}$ to still uniformly capture the $1$ and the $-\frac{1}{2^2}$, respectively.

Comment: @lulu What i am doing is grouping? I think is a bit different?

Comment: It's true that if you have two series, one of which diverges and one of which converges, and you intermix them in any possible fashion, the intermixed series diverges as well. That is in fact a legitimate theorem and therefore a legitimate rule for reasoning about series convergence/divergence properties, despite all the skepticism from other commenters (one of whom is apparently you yourself, Sorfosh? That second to last comment of yours confuses me…). Thus, the proof you proffer is indeed a fine proof.

Comment: If the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{(2n+2)^2}\right)$ converges, then so does the sum of series $$\sum_{n=0}\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{(2n+2)^2}\right)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+2)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2n+1}$$So, we can conclude ...

Comment: Yes, you are adding consecutive terms in pairs.  To be sure, in this case I expect you can show that the grouping is justified.  But I expect you'd have to go through some variant of the partial sum argument to do it.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thats pretty much reverse engineering the proof that a sum of convergent series and divergent series is divergent. Essentially, the same proof i did. So i am assuming its correct?

Comment: @lulu can i just assume that it is convergent, group, and then come to a contradiction?

Comment: Well, no.  It is easy to show that the sum of convergent series is also convergent.  So, I showed that the series of interest cannot be convergent by contradiction.  Your explanation was an ad hoc splitting of a series that might not be convergent.

Comment: Grouping terms in divergent series is risky.  I'd never do it casually.  Always best to look at the partial sums.

Comment: @Dr.MV I did not split the series. Sum $x_n$ is divergent and Sum $y_n$ convergent, then Sum $x_n +y_n$ is divergent. Now i am saying Sum $x_n$ is divergent and Sum $y_n$ is convergent, therefore Sum $x_n+y_n$ is divergent. I am not splitting it, i am creating it. But apparently, when finding the formula for the terms, i grouped them so this approach is invalid anyway.

Comment: The grouping is mostly a problem if you are grouping non-conditionally convergent series.

Comment: @Sorfosh  To be clear, it isn't "invalid" it just requires justification.  It is certainly true that if $\sum a_n=\infty$ and $\sum b_n<\infty$ then $a_1-b_1+a_2-b_2+\cdots$ diverges.  My point is that this needs to be proven (and that looking at the partial sums yields a proof).

Comment: @Sorfosh That is the virtue of pursuing this using the way forward that I outlined for you.  ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV but you used my formula for the series, which i acquired by grouping. And since we cannot group, my formula is not necessarily correct for infinite series. I am having really hard time grasping it

Answer (score 3):

Call $s_k$ the partial sums of the series. That is $s_k=\sum_{n=1}^ka_n$, where $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ if $n$ is odd, and $a_n=-\frac{1}{n^2}$ if $n$ is even. As $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, we have the estimate
$$
s_k\geq-\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\sum_{n=1}^ka_{2n-1}=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{2n-1}.
$$
By comparison with the harmonic series the last sum is divergent (when $k\to\infty$) so $s_k$ must be too, proving that your series diverges.

Comment: I see, to i just show that partial sum is unbounded for k-> infinity, hence the series does not converge.

Comment: @Sorfosh Yeah, going back to the partial sums is always a reasonable way to prove divergence/convergence.

Comment: Wait, but are you not grouping the terms? Just like i did, which makes it invalid?

Comment: @Sorfosh No, grouping is allowed for finite/partial sums, but not on a series itself.  And if it converged with the grouping, then there may be need to go back and check more.

Comment: But the moment we say that k goes to infinity, we are saying that this grouping is okay, thats how we got the bound

Comment: As commented above by @lulu yes, I am grouping terms, but I am doing it in a way way weaker than you did. Notice that I am just grouping consecutove terms.

Comment: @mathbeing That actually doesn't help, as with the $1-1+1-1+\dots$ case.

Comment: @SimpleArt Exactly, since we sort of extrapolate to infinity, we are baisically grouping the terms till infinity, the moment k-> infinity.

Comment: @Sorfosh Ok, so $1)$ grouping on the partial sums is ok and $2)$ grouping cannot make a convergent series diverge.  Since grouping here shows divergence, the original series must be divergent.  If it showed convergence, then it could've been either convergent or divergent.

Comment: Do you know the theorem that state that? I would really appriciate it.

Comment: @SimpleArt Fair point. Let me edit the answer...

Comment: @Sorfosh Assuming you do not reorder terms when grouping, the absolute value of the partial sums with grouping will always be less than or equal to the absolute value of the partial sums without grouping, and then be comparison, grouping will make convergent series look... convergent.  On the other hand, we have proof by construction that the divergent series $1-1+1-1+\dots$ can appear to converge via grouping.

Comment: @SimpleArt It should be fine now.

Comment: @SimpleArt I am confused now, how is grouping partial sums that tend to infinity any different than grouping the whole series?

Comment: @Sorfosh Does grouping have any affect on finite sums?  On the other hand, we have the Riemann rearrangement theorem.

Comment: @SimpleArt No, it does not. I am okay with saying that $s_k>pi^2/6+sum 1/(2n-1) from 1 to k. But when we say k-> goes to infinity we are grouping infinitely many terms now.

Comment: @Sorfosh The manner that we do it is well-defined.  Indeed, refer back to the definition of what it means to have an infinite sum.  May also help to think about limits of sub-sequences and what they tell us about limits of the entire sequence.

Comment: This seems exactly what i did. I said the my formula works for finite numbers and then said k-> ifinity. Exactly the same as we did here. I do not see the difference. In both cases our formulas work for a finite k, but problems come in when k is infnite.

Comment: @Sorfosh What is different about your method and the above method when working with $S=1-1+1-1+\dots$?

Comment: Well using my method we get $\sum{(-1)^{n+1}-1}=1-1+-1...$ Since we have two divergent series inside, we do not know if the series is divergent or convergent, using my method.

Comment: @simpleArt using the partial sum method, we need to divide into cases k is even or k is odd. This ruins our k-> infinity since it is not even nor odd. So partial sums do not work here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47905/discussion-between-sorfosh-and-simple-art).

Answer (score 3):

First, there seems to be quite a bit of confusion in the comments concerning "grouping". Let's take a look at it, essentially:

\begin{align}
1 - \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4^2} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6^2} +\cdots &\stackrel{?}{=}
\left(1 - \frac{1}{2^2}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4^2}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6^2}\right) + \cdots \\ &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2n + 1} - \frac{1}{(2n + 2)^2}\right).
\end{align}

Now, when you say that you're "not allowed to group", I guess you're right in that you've generated a somewhat different series *but* the two series are concretely related. In particular, if the left side converges, then the right side must also converge. This is a special case of the fact that, if a sequence converges, then any subsequence of that sequence also converges. Specifically, if we let $s_n$ denote the $n^{\text{th}}$ partial sum of the series on the left and we let

$$S_n = \sum_{n=0}^n \left(\frac{1}{2n + 1} - \frac{1}{(2n + 2)^2}\right)$$

denote the $n^{\text{th}}$ partial sum of the series on the right, then $S_n = s_{2n}$. Thus, $S_n$ is a subsequence of $s_n$ and, if $s_n$ converges then $S_n$ must converge to the same limit. Taking the contrapositive, if $S_n$ diverges, then $s_n$ must also diverge.

I think you make a mistake, though, at the next step by breaking the series up into two series. You are essentially [rearranging the series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) which is only valid when the series is absolutely convergent.

The approach at this point is to simply combine the fractions to get
$$\frac{1}{2n + 1} - \frac{1}{(2n + 2)^2} = \frac{4 n^2+6 n+3}{4 (n+1)^2 (2 n+1)},$$
to which the limit comparison test is easily applicable.

This is exactly the approach I took in my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463991).